# 0-5V 1A Dual Output DC Power Supply - SOFTWARE CONTROLLED

Tags: dc, power-supply

I am interested in purchasing (or building but preferably purchase) a software controlled DC power supply.  Preferably, would like to control the output using LabVIEW.

I need two separate outputs that can be controlled from 0-5V as accurately as possible (5mV resolution).  Each output must be able to source up to 1A.

I am planning on using the supplies to control the brightness of two separate high powered LED's.

Can't seem to find much from Google.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: An Agilent E3646A would seem to meet those specs. Not sure about LabView support but would be suprised if it didn't have support.

Comment: I don't understand the two votes to close -- this question certainly does involve electronic design, as the OP is saying he wants to either buy or build a programmable supply.  My answer covers the latter.

Answer (score 2):

You could build an inexpensive supply using a pair of [LT3081 positive adjustable regulators](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LT3081ET7%23PBF/LT3081ET7%23PBF-ND/4156528).  Unlike other adjustable regulators like the LM317, the LT3081 can be adjusted all the way down to 0V.

Adjustment of the voltage is done via a single resistor, 20k per volt.  So 0 ohms is 0v, 20K is 1V, and 100k is 5V.

For programming, you could use the [X9119TV14-2.7 digital potentiometer](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/X9119TV14-2.7/X9119TV14-2.7-ND/387313).  It's maximum value is 100k ohms, which matches the 5V setting of the regulator, and has 1024 steps, which provides 5 mV resolution you specified (most digital pots have only 256 steps or less).